# Anti-Vowel program Issue

Tags: python

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    new = ''
    for char in text:
        if char in "aeiou" or char in "AEIOU":
            ala = text.replace(char, '')
    new = new + ala
    return new
print anti_vowel("Hey look Words!")
```

It returns 'Hey lk Wrds!' which means that the function somehow completely overlooked the "e".

Answer (score 6):

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    new = ''
    for char in text:
        if char in "aeiou" or char in "AEIOU":
            ala = text.replace(char, '')
```

Let's stop here and look at what happens:

For each character in the message, if the character is a vowel, you make a copy of the original text with *that vowel* removed. Then you assign it to `ala`... but?

```
    new = new + ala
    return new
```

The indentation means that `new = new + ala` *only runs once* - after your for loop is finished. On your sample data, "Hey look Words!", the last vowel you saw was 'o', so `ala` contains a string with no 'o's (but all other vowels left alone):

```
print anti_vowel("Hey look Words!")   # => "Hey lk Wrds!"
print anti_vowel("aeiouAEIOU!")       # => "aeiouAEIO!"
```

(Your test string only had two vowel-characters, 'e' and 'o', which meant you couldn't see any difference between "why is the e not removed?" and "why is *only* the o removed?", which would have been a more obvious indicator of the problem!)

Fixing your code directly would look like

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    result = text
    for char in text:
        if char in "aeiouAEIOU":
            result = result.replace(char, '')
    return result
```

but a more Pythonic approach is:

```
# a set allows very fast look-ups
VOWELS = set("aeiouAEIOU")

def no_vowels(s):
    # keep every character that is not a vowel
    return "".join(ch for ch in s if ch not in VOWELS)

print(no_vowels("Look Ma, no vowels!"))  # => "Lk M, n vwls!"
```

Comment: You should also suggest using `string.translate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead check if `char` is not a vowel. If it is not, then add it to the string:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    new = ''
    for char in text:
        if char not in "aeiouAEIOU":
            new += char
    return new
```

**Note** that it would be better to use

```
if char not in "aeiouAEIOU":
```

or (as @Michal commented):

```
 if char.lower not in "aeiou":
```

instead of

```
if char not in "aeiou" and char not in "AEIOU":
```

Comment: To shorten the loop I'd suggest `if char.lower not in "aeiou"`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing the replace on `text` every time, not on the updated variable `ala`. Try this instead:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    new = ''
    ala = text
    for char in text:
        if char in "aeiou" or char in "AEIOU":
            ala = ala.replace(char, '')
    new = new + ala
    return new
print anti_vowel("Hey look Words!")
```

Comment: But if I do the replacing on text, aiou gets replaced every time. Why just e?

Comment: Because only the last vowel that matched would have been replaced. If you have `Hey look words` you get `Hey lk wrds`; `Help me please` would be `Hlp m plas`; `Hey man how are you` would be `Hey man how are yo`. Only the last matching vowel would get replaced, because you were doing `text.replace`, not `ala.replace`. `text` is the same each time.

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Python. So when you do the following,

```
ala = text.replace(char, '')
```

this create a new string replacing `char` with empty string and assigns it to `ala`. However, the value of `text` is still the same original string the function `anti_vowel` was passed. After the loop terminates, value of `ala` will be the original string with all occurrences of the last vowel removed. What you should do instead is -

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    for char in text:
        if char in "aeiouAEIOU":
            # update text after replacing all instances of the vowel
            # char in text with the empty string
            text = text.replace(char, '')
    return text
```

You might also consider using the string method [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate).

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    return text.translate(None, vowels)
```